# What expression are these titles alluding to?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

There are two episode titles from two separate shows that are written similarly:

- From Castle: *The mistress always spanks twice*
- From Doc Martin: *The GP always rings twice*

Episode titles are usually clever plays on words, so I'm assuming the two titles are alluding to a common expression. What expression (or other cultural reference) are the titles making a reference to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably from the novel ‘The Postman Always Rings Twice’ by James M Cain, published in 1934: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Postman_Always_Rings_Twice_%28novel%29